FreeBSD: Daemonize a Script
I have written a simple NodeJS application and I would like to have FreeBSD launch it, and if the application ever crashes or terminates for any reason, relaunch it. The goal is for this application to be running as close to "eternally" as possible.
I think that daemon might do what I need with -r, but I haven't found an invocation that behaves exactly as I described above. How can daemon accomplish my task, and if it can't, what alternative can I use?

Turns out, I've been using daemon -r correctly the whole time and it's actually a bug in my environment that I've run into.
https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/warning-dont-upgrade-your-truenas-core-jails-to-freebsd-13-3-just-yet.117018/
The host OS is FreeBSD 13.1, and the jail's OS is FreeBSD 13.3, which causes a weird issue where daemon only functions if most of its options are not invoked. Always remember that there's a chance that you've read the manual correctly and that the manual simply doesn't apply to your situation.
